# React Native TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.data.map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reusability

I decide to reuse a component that I thought would work for my new application that is pulling in a third-party API.

The reusable component in question is iterating `this.props.data.map()` which is evaluating as being undefined in my `components/Swipe.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  Dimensions,
  LayoutAnimation,
  UIManager
} from "react-native";

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 0.25 * SCREEN_WIDTH;
const SWIPE_OUT_DURATION = 250;

class Swipe extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onSwipeRight: () => {},
    onSwipeLeft: () => {}
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const position = new Animated.ValueXY();
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        position.setValue({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy });
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dx > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
          this.forceSwipe("right");
        } else if (gestureState.dx < -SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
          this.forceSwipe("left");
        } else {
          this.resetPosition();
        }
      }
    });

    this.state = { panResponder, position, index: 0 };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.setState({ index: 0 });
    }
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
  }

  forceSwipe(direction) {
    const x = direction === "right" ? SCREEN_WIDTH : -SCREEN_WIDTH;
    Animated.timing(this.state.position, {
      toValue: { x, y: 0 },
      duration: SWIPE_OUT_DURATION
    }).start(() => this.onSwipeComplete(direction));
  }

  onSwipeComplete(direction) {
    const { onSwipeLeft, onSwipeRight, data } = this.props;
    const item = data[this.state.index];
    direction === "right" ? onSwipeRight(item) : onSwipeLeft(item);
    this.state.position.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    this.setState({ index: this.state.index + 1 });
  }

  resetPosition() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.position, {
      toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }).start();
  }

  getCardStyle() {
    const { position } = this.state;
    const rotate = position.x.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH * 1.5, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH * 1.5],
      outputRange: ["-120deg", "0deg", "120deg"]
    });
    return {
      ...position.getLayout(),
      transform: [{ rotate }]
    };
  }

  renderCards() {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (this.state.index >= this.props.data.length) {
      return this.props.renderNoMoreCards();
    }
    return this.props.data
      .map((item, i) => {
        if (i < this.state.index) {
          return null;
        }
        if (i === this.state.index) {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={item[this.props.id]}
              style={[this.getCardStyle(), styles.cardStyle]}
              {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers}
            >
              {this.props.renderCard(item)}
            </Animated.View>
          );
        }
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={item[this.props.id]}
            style={[styles.cardStyle, { top: 10 * (i - this.state.index) }]}
          >
            {this.props.renderCard(item)}
          </Animated.View>
        );
      })
      .reverse();
  }

  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderCards()}</View>;
  }
}

const styles = {
  cardStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH
  }
};

export default Swipe;
```

I am unclear why this is happening since I do get back a `payload: data` in my action creator:

```
export const fetchJobs = (region, callback) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url =
      JOB_ROOT_URL +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.key +
      "&method=" +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.method +
      "&category=" +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.keyword +
      "&format=" +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.format;
    let { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: data });
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

So why is `data` evaluating as undefined in my reusable component?

It's being called here in `DeckScreen.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import { Card, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import Swipe from "../components/Swipe";

class DeckScreen extends Component {
  renderCard(job) {
    return (
      <Card title={job.title}>
        <View style={styles.detailWrapper}>
          <Text>{job.company}</Text>
          <Text>{job.post_date}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>
          {job.description.replace(/<span>/g, "").replace(/<\/span>/g, "")}
        </Text>
      </Card>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Swipe data={this.props.jobs} renderCard={this.renderCard} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  detailWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginBottom: 10
  }
};

function mapStateToProps({ jobs }) {
  return { jobs: jobs.listing };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DeckScreen);
```

The button I am pressing that gives me this error is in the `MapScreen` screen:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { MapView } from "expo";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import * as actions from "../actions";

class MapScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    region: {
      longitude: 30.2672,
      latitude: 97.7431,
      longitudeDelta: 0.04,
      latitudeDelta: 0.09
    }
  };

  onButtonPress = () => {
    this.props.fetchJobs(this.state.region, () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("deck");
    });
  };

  getLocationHandler = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
      const currentCoords = {
        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
        latitude: pos.coords.latitude
      };

      this.goToLocation(currentCoords);
    });
  };

  goToLocation = coords => {
    this.map.animateToRegion({
      ...this.state.region,
      longitude: coords.longitude,
      latitude: coords.latitude
    });
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        region: {
          ...prevState.region,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
          latitude: coords.latitude
        }
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            title="Search This Area"
            icon={{ name: "search" }}
            onPress={this.onButtonPress}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button
            title="My Location"
            icon={{ name: "map" }}
            onPress={this.getLocationHandler}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  buttonContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 50,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  }
};

export default connect(
  null,
  actions
)(MapScreen);
```

This should be an array of objects as verified here:
[image]

And in my reducer I have:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  listing: []
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I added some verbose error handling and this is what I got back:

> [02:25:28] fetchJobs Action Error: Given action "fetch_jobs", reducer
>   "jobs" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly
>   return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value,
>   you can return null instead of undefined.

So it seems like the problem is in the `jobs_reducer`:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  listing: []
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I don't know if I am just too exhausted at this point, but I have tried `listings: []`, I have tried `listing: []`, I am out of ideas of how to get this reducer to not return `undefined` because even when I do this:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

// const INITIAL_STATE = {
//   listing: []
// };

export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I get the same error message.

My idea with creating an `INITIAL_STATE` and setting it to `listing: []` is to ensure I could map over this array and never worry about the case where I have not yet fetched the list of jobs.

So I am perplexed as to exactly where I am getting this undefined since I did set the initial state to null and I was still getting that error.

So in the process of debugging I then tried this:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

// const INITIAL_STATE = {
//   listing: []
// };

export default function(state = null, action) {
  console.log("action is", action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And got that the `payload` is undefined:

```
Please check your inputs.
[09:39:38] action is Object {
[09:39:38]   "payload": undefined,
[09:39:38]   "type": "fetch_jobs",
[09:39:38] }
```

I have hit a wall here. I did a whole refactor to my `jobs` action creator and logged out the `payload` property:

```
export const fetchJobs = (region, distance = 10) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = buildJobsUrl();
    let job_list = await axios.get(url);
    job_list = locationify(
      region,
      console.log(job_list.data.listings.listing),
      job_list.data.listings.listing,
      distance,
      (obj, coords) => {
        obj.company.location = { ...obj.company.location, coords };
        return obj;
      }
    );
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: job_list });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("fetchJobs Action Error:", e.message);
  }
};
```

The `console.log(job_list.data.listings.listing)` logged out the data to my terminal successfully and yet my `payload` property is still undefined, how is that possible?

I got the action creator and reducer working by refactoring the action creator to just this:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Location } from "expo";
import qs from "qs";

import { FETCH_JOBS } from "./types";
// import locationify from "../tools/locationify";

const JOB_ROOT_URL = "https://authenticjobs.com/api/?";

const JOB_QUERY_PARAMS = {
  api_key: "<api_key>",
  method: "aj.jobs.search",
  perpage: "10",
  format: "json",
  keywords: "javascript"
};

const buildJobsUrl = zip => {
  const query = qs.stringify({ ...JOB_QUERY_PARAMS });
  return `${JOB_ROOT_URL}${query}`;
};

export const fetchJobs = (region, callback) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    let zip = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(region);
    const url = buildJobsUrl(zip);
    console.log(url);
    let { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: data });
    callback();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

So the problem is no longer there in theory, right. Then, when I bring in the `Swipe.js` component, the problem returns, in particular the problem seems to be with this code here:

```
renderCards() {
    if (this.state.index >= this.props.data.length) {
      return this.props.renderNoMoreCards();
    }

    return this.props.data
      .map((item, i) => {
        if (i < this.state.index) {
          return null;
        }

        if (i === this.state.index) {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={item[this.props.id]}
              style={[this.getCardStyle(), styles.cardStyle]}
              {...this.state.panResponder.panHandlers}
            >
              {this.props.renderCard(item)}
            </Animated.View>
          );
        }
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={item[this.props.id]}
            style={[styles.cardStyle, { top: 10 * (i - this.state.index) }]}
          >
            {this.props.renderCard(item)}
          </Animated.View>
        );
      })
      .reverse();
  }
```

This is where I start to hit a roadblock again.

Comment: Seems like `this.props.jobs` in `DeckScreen` may be undefined. Would you post how you set the attributes to the `DeckScreen` element?

Comment: @JuanScolari, I posted all the code to `DeckScreen` and also `MapScreen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what helped was refactoring my `jobs_reducer` file from:

```
import { FETCH_JOBS } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  listing: []
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

to this:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_JOBS:
      const { listings } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, listing: listings.listing };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Props are not available immediatelly from redux store on render, it comes asyncrounously. 
To select data from redux store better to use **save navigation**:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  jobs: state && state.jobs && state.jobs.listing
})
```

Than again on render to check if data exists or not:

```
...
render() {
   const { jobs } = this.props;
   return (
     <View>
      {jobs && <Swipe data={jobs} renderCard={this.renderCard} />}
    </View>

}

...

renderCards() {
  const { data } = this.props;
  return data && data.map((item, index) => {
...
```

Comment: I tried `mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { jobs: state.jobs.listings };
};`, it did not help.

Comment: You need to check on render too. I completed my answer a bit.

Comment: When I run your code above I get the message `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jobs`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to deconstruct it form this props. I corrected.

Comment: I followed your answer and this time I do get all the data logging out to my terminal but on the mobile device UI I eventually get the same error. Not sure what to make of that.

Answer (score 0):

**map** function generally iterate through array-object. You are trying to iterate through a non-array object. So first check the type of the object using `typeof(variable)` then use the function.

Comment: Where do you see that I am trying to iterate through a non-array?

Comment: you are getting data from an endpoint and dispatching as payload . Please check the the data you are getting from endpoint is undefined or not or a non array object. use console.log(data) then see the type of data.